# Diaply Header Name in all the pages in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working on a report where i gropued the date based on Employee_ID, and my report should fetch the details of the report based on Employee_ID.

1. Inside my report i have 4 parameters like Employe_name which is drop
   down field and multiselect value.
2. AsoFDate parameter, which is text field. and two more parameters.

   i have selected two values from employee_name parameter, for example i selected ram and rahul two employees from employee_name parameter, my report has to fetch the details of ram and rahul based on their Eid.

on page one details of ram, and on page 2 details of rahul. upto here it is working fine fine for me. Now i need to display the names of the employee at top of report.

For example if am fetching the results of ram, my report has to show the deatils of Ram like this

```
Ram  

DepatID   Designation  salary  
1         Programmer    20k
```

then when i move on to next page, it should fetch rahul details like

```
Rahul  

 DepatID   Designation  salary  
    1       Programmer    20k  
    2       programmer    45K
```

i am able to display the details, but not the employee_names Ram and Rahul at the top of corresponding report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i sorted out this issue, i placed employee_name parameter inside the table tablix. Now am able to get the desired outcome.